# make a pivot table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, cron

I have a table which contain below information:

[image]

now I need to do pivot like this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select hk_district,
       sum(complaint_no) filter (where month = '201801') as compaints_201801,
       sum(complaint_no) filter (where month = '201802') as compaints_201802,
       sum(complaint_no) filter (where month = '201803') as compaints_201803
from t
group by hk_district;
```

Comment: Can I use crontabe instead of conditional? There are few month in my table. I just caputre three months for example.